# Multiple d3 charts on a page with different (linear and log) axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've built a page with five d3.js charts.  Four of them use standard linear axes (linear data over time), and the fifth chart uses log/log axes.  So far, I can get either the linear charts to render correctly, or the log/log chart to render correctly, but not both.

**Question --** how can I define log/log axes for the final chart while keeping the first four linear charts working correctly?

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Overall chart settings
var divwidth = $("#collapseOne").width();
var divheight = $(window).height();

var margin = {top: 25, right: 60, bottom: 35, left: 80},
    width = divwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 0.65*divheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
</script>
```

Then I define the first chart:

```
<script>
// Chart1 - NumofCompanies chart settings
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.cumcos); });

var chart1 = d3.select("#collapseOne")
  .append("div")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("/monthly.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.cumcos; }));

  chart1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  chart1.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of companies");

  chart1.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line1);

});

function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.cumcos = +d.cumcos;
  return d;
}
</script>
```

and then the log/log chart

```
<script>
// Chart5 - Log/log chart
var x = d3.scale.log()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.log()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line5 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(de) { return x(de.ordernum); })
    .y(function(de) { return y(de.sumfunding); });

var chart5 = d3.select("#collapseFive").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("/loglog.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(de) { return de.ordernum; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(de) { return de.sumfunding; }));

  chart5.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  chart5.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sum of Funding ($)");

  chart5.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line5);
});

function type(de) {
  de.ordernum = +de.ordernum;
  de.sumfunding = +de.sumfunding;
  return de;
}

</script>
```

**edit** - I've also tried renaming variables like this below and it still doesn't work; the axes are still linear.  And when I try changing things like x.domain to xlog.domain and .x(function(de to .xlog(function(de then nothing on the chart renders at all.

```
<script>
// Chart5 - Log/log chart
var xlog = d3.scale.log()
    .range([0, width]);

var ylog = d3.scale.log()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxislog = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xlog)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxislog = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(ylog)
    .orient("left");

var line5 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(de) { return x(de.ordernum); })
    .y(function(de) { return y(de.sumfunding); });

var chart5 = d3.select("#collapseFive").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("/loglog.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(de) { return de.ordernum; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(de) { return de.sumfunding; }));

  chart5.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxislog);

  chart5.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxislog)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sum of Funding ($)");

  chart5.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line5);
});

function type(de) {
  de.ordernum = +de.ordernum;
  de.sumfunding = +de.sumfunding;
  return de;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Use different variable names so they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that I already tried that.  I've tried substituting xlog for x, ylog for y, xAxislog for xAxis, yAxislog for yAxis, but within the d3.svg.line calls when I substitute .xlog(function for .x(function that doesn't work, either.

Comment: you're still using the `y` scale for the last chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking the first `x` in the line generator with the variable `x` in your scale:

```
var line5 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(de) { return x(de.ordernum); })
   //^--this has to be "x"   ^--this is the scale
```

So, it has to be:

```
var line5 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(de) { return xLog(de.ordernum); })
    .y(function(de) { return yLog(de.sumfunding); });
```

According to the [API of version 3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#line):

> line.x - get or set the x-coordinate accessor.
>
> line.y - get or set the y-coordinate accessor.

As a good practice, avoid variable names like `x`. Instead, use names like `xScale`, `xAxis`, `xPosition` etc.

Comment: Ahh!  Thank you, I was having trouble figuring that out from the d3.js documentation.  Strangely, both axes now go from 1-10, when the source data goes from 1-~500 on one axis and 2*10^6 - 1*10^9 on the other axis.

Comment: That's because you're messing the variable names again! It has to be `xLog.domain(...` inside the `d3.tsv` function, not `x.domain(...`. The same for `yLog`.

Comment: That's it! I was having a really hard time figuring out which "x"'s were using variables and which were required by d3.  It's working perfectly now.